# How to slice byte string?

Tags: python

I have a byte string e.g. `b"\x00\x01\x02\x03"`, and I want to slice it into two byte strings: `b"\x00\x01"` and `b"\x02\x03"`. What's the most pythonic way to do this? Edit: I have already tried [:2] and [2:]. Is there any other way of doing this, and what is the preferred way?

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried indexing?

Comment: I was able to do it by doing [:2] and [2:], but I was wondering if there are any other methods and what's the most preferred method.

Comment: Edit it to what?

Comment: to show what you have tried so people will not recommend using what you have already used.

Comment: Slice notation is the obvious way to make slices. It's a bit puzzling that you think there ought to be another. The Zen of Python says *There should be one– and preferably only one –obvious way to do it.*